# Подзапрос SQL oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте, существует рабочая процедура удаления строки, но преподавателя такой вариант не устраивает. Прошу помощи в составлении правильного подзапроса. 
И если можно, объясните пожалуйста, почему мой вариант плох.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5):

В Вашем случае использование `SELECT` могло бы быть оправдано, так как Вы дважды используете результат полученного запроса. Однако из второй таблицы вы удаляете по тем же условиям, которые используете в `Select` и соответственно второй запрос не понадобится. В операции Delete можно использовать подзапросы, по этому удаления в Вашей процедуре можно переписать например так:

```
DELETE FROM customer 
WHERE  fnum in 
(
  SELECT fnum  
  FROM   firm
  WHERE  fname = name 
);
DELETE FROM firm
where  fname = name;
```

Так же обратите внимание, что в текущей процедуре есть 2 потенциальных ошибки:

1) `TO_MANY_ROWS` - исключение может возникнуть, если значения `fname` в таблице не уникальны. Запрос вернет более 1 строки и такой результат не получится сохранить в переменную.

2) `NO_DATA_FOUND` - исключение может возникнуть, если в таблице не окажется ни 1го значения по условию `fname = name`.

**UPD**

Обновил ответ, так как не сразу заметил, что из второй таблицы удаление идет по тому же значению, по которому выбирается в `SELECT`. Преподаватель во всем прав.

Comment: Лучше переписать на JOIN или EXISTS - обычно оно побыстрее...

Comment: В `Oracle` нельзя написать `JOIN` в `Delete`. Про `EXISTS`  в таком запросе не должно быть разницы в скорости выполнения.

Comment: При большой таблице `firm` и отсутствии индекса по `firm.fname` разница должна быть, и заметная...

Comment: @Akina я сейчас попробовал построить планы для обоих случаев. В случае с `IN` оракл успешно показывает в плане `hash join` после `full scan`. В случае `exists` в плане получается `full scan` c последующим `filter`, что может выполняться довольно медленно. Что тут действительно окажется быстрее сложно сказать

Comment: С учётом того, что подзапрос вернёт скорее всего одну, ну максимум две, записи, `filter` может оказаться побыстрее... у него накладных расходов меньше. К тому же `exists` предполагает прерывание поиска после обнаружения первого соответствия, что вряд ли реализовано при `hash join` - постоянная проверка на непустость текущего результата дорого обойдётся.

Comment: @Akina А вот у меня на двух не маленьких таблицах все зависит от того, сколько записей _предполагается_ найти в подзапросе и есть ли индекс на fname. В случае если оптимизатор ожидает мало записей, он выполняет внутренний по index range или full scan, после чего сортирует результат по fnum и nested loops удаляет так же по index range. В случае если записей _предполагается_ много выполняет full scan (или index_ffs), sort uniq fnum и hash join right semi двух full scan для IN. или обычный hash join двух full scan для exists. предсказания по скорости для IN при этом лучше

Comment: Потенциальных ошибок в селекте на самом деле две - `too_many_rows` и `no_data_found`. Ну и плюс совсем экзотика - если вдруг поле `fnum` окажется не числом. Для этого можно было бы использовать тип `firm.fnum%type`, если селект нужно оставить.

Comment: @Dmitry действительно, NO_DATA_FOUND я как то упустил

Answer (score 4):

Потому что и в самом деле можно через подзапрос:

```
DELETE
  FROM customer
 WHERE fnum = (SELECT fnum
                 FROM firm
                WHERE fname = name);
```

В теории, полагаю, он прав: зачем создание лишней переменной, обращение к ней и т.д., если можно обойтись одним запросом, тем самым дав движку Oracle шанс построить оптимальный план. На практике разница, наверное, исчезающе мала. Думаю, что на самом деле Вас хотят научить применять подзапросы.

Comment: Запрос в общем ошибочен - нигде нет гарантии уникальности fname, можно получить ошибку surquery returns more than 1 row. Можно поправить, добавив, например, SOME.

Comment: Из контекста я бы подразумевал, что fnum - первичный ключ.

Comment: Это да. Но выбирается-то он по заданному `fname`, которое не то что не первичный, но и не обязан быть unique. Так что одному `name` могут соответствовать несколько `fnum`.

Comment: Ну и тут на ошибку студенту не указали. Жаловались именно на отсутствие подзапроса.